# Why does the click event not work in TableView set to editing?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

In my Appcelerator Titanium iOS-App I have a TableView with different Rows representing a menu for my app.

The first row is a link back to a different navigation level. On this row editable is set to false.

When call setEditing on the TableView I am able to delete rows (not the first one). The delete-Event is fired.
I would like to get the TableView **click event**, but it seems, that this event is **not fired**, when the table is set to editing.

I'm using SDK 4.1.0.GA on iOS Simulator or Device (iPad).

Is this an error in Titanium or iOS or is this like a desired behaviour?